# Uninstall plugin in sonarqube: can only be uninstalled as part of a SonarSource edition

Tags: sonarqube

I've accidently installed the branch plugin on SonarQube. We use the free commercial edition. Now it complains about:

> Analyses suspended. Please set a valid license for the commercial
>   features you installed.Go to License page.

I tried to uninstall the plugin with:

```
curl -X POST -u "xxx" "https://server.com/sonar/api/plugins/uninstall?key=branch"
```

I didn't found any 'uninstall' button or something.

But it replies with:

```
{"errors":[{"msg":"SonarSource commercial plugin with key 'branch' can only be uninstalled as part of a SonarSource edition"}]}
```

How can I remove this plugin?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can stop the SonarQube server and remove the added plugin by hand (see the plugins folder on the SonarQube server). Look at all the SonarQube log files during the restart in order to check for other issues.